# Get timeslots from starting and ending time

Tags: javascript

I want timeslots from starting time and ending time with a given interval. also need to check that if the provided date is same as today's date then start time would be the current time of particular region. (like if time is `10:12` then we need to start from `10:30` and if time is `10:36` then opt for `11:00` (i.e. from 1 minute to 29 we should opt 30 minutes and from 31 to 59 we should opt 00) ).

So, how can I achieve that using given values below?

**Input:**

```
let date = "20-07-2019" 
let startTime = "10:00";
let endtime = "14:00";
let interval = 60; // in minutes
```

**Expected Output:**

```
["10:00 - 11:00", "11:00- 12:00" , "12:00- 13:00", "13:00 - 14:00"]
```

**My code:**

```js
let parseTime = (s) => {
  let c = s.split(':');
  return parseInt(c[0]) * 60 + parseInt(c[1]);
}

let convertHours = (mins) => {
  let hour = Math.floor(mins / 60);
  mins = mins % 60;
  let converted = pad(hour, 2) + ':' + pad(mins, 2);
  return converted;
}

let pad = (str, max) => {
  str = str.toString();
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}

let calculate_time_slot = (start_time, end_time, interval) => {
  let i, formatted_time;
  let time_slots = new Array();
  for (let i = start_time; i <= end_time; i = i + interval) {
    formatted_time = convertHours(i);
    time_slots.push(formatted_time);
  }
  return time_slots;
}

let date = "20-07-2019"
let startTime = "10:00";
let endTime = "14:00";
let interval = 60; // in minutes
start_time = parseTime(startTime)
end_time = parseTime(endTime)
let times_ara = calculate_time_slot(start_time, end_time, interval);

console.log(times_ara);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd change the for loop to a while, then increment for the interval in the loop so you have both the start and end times in the loop, e.g.

```js
let parseTime = (s) => {
  let c = s.split(':');
  return parseInt(c[0]) * 60 + parseInt(c[1]);
}

let convertHours = (mins) => {
  let hour = Math.floor(mins / 60);
  mins = mins % 60;
  let converted = pad(hour, 2) + ':' + pad(mins, 2);
  return converted;
}

let pad = (str, max) => {
  str = str.toString();
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}

let calculate_time_slot = (start_time, end_time, interval) => {
  let i, formatted_time;
  let time_slots = new Array();
  // Round start and end times to next 30 min interval
  start_time = Math.ceil(start_time / 30) * 30;
  end_time = Math.ceil(end_time / 30) * 30;

  // Start and end of interval in the loop
  while (start_time < end_time) {
    let t = convertHours(start_time) + ' - ' + (convertHours(start_time += interval));
    time_slots.push(t);
  }
  return time_slots;
}

let date = "20-07-2019"
let startTime = "10:00";
let endtime = "14:00";
let interval = 60; // in minutes
let end_time = parseTime(endtime)
let start_time = parseTime(startTime)

let times_ara = calculate_time_slot(start_time, end_time, interval);

console.log(times_ara);
```

There's quite a bit of other stuff I'd change too, but that's the minimum to get your desired result.

Oh, I added a bit to round to the next 30 minute interval 'cos that's what you said you wanted too.

Answer (score 2):

This is the shortest I got.

```
let calculate_time_slot = (start_time, end_time, interval) => {
  const timeSlots = [];
  for (let i = start_time; i < end_time; i += interval) {
    const formattedBegin = convertHours(i);
    const formattedEnd = convertHours(i + interval);
    timeSlots.push(formattedBegin + ' - ' + formattedEnd);
  }
  return timeSlots;
}
```

Runnable snippet:

```js
let parseTime = (s) => {
  let c = s.split(':');
  return parseInt(c[0]) * 60 + parseInt(c[1]);
}

let convertHours = (mins) => {
  let hour = Math.floor(mins / 60);
  mins = mins % 60;
  let converted = pad(hour, 2) + ':' + pad(mins, 2);
  return converted;
}

let pad = (str, max) => {
  str = str.toString();
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}

let calculate_time_slot = (start_time, end_time, interval) => {
  const timeSlots = [];
  for (let i = start_time; i < end_time; i += interval) {
    const formattedBegin = convertHours(i);
    const formattedEnd = convertHours(i + interval);
    timeSlots.push(formattedBegin + ' - ' + formattedEnd);
  }
  return timeSlots;
}

let date = "20-07-2019"
let startTime = "10:00";
let endTime = "14:00";
let interval = 60; // in minutes
start_time = parseTime(startTime)
end_time = parseTime(endTime)
let times_ara = calculate_time_slot(start_time, end_time, interval);

console.log(times_ara);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function seems to generate the required values you just need to change how they are represented, here is a way of doing that:

```js
let time_slots = ["10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00"];

time_slots = time_slots.reduce((a, c, i, arr) => {
  if (i < arr.length - 1) {
    a.push(`${c} - ${arr[i + 1]}`);
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(time_slots);
```